# net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added - ERROR

Tags: cucumber, reporting

My Cucumber reports are not getting generated. I have created my small Spring Boot project and tried to create cucumber tests on it, i am able to load the application and run the cucumber tests on the same, but when i added plugins & dependencies for the report generation, i am getting the error - net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!

**Please note: My cucumber tests are part of a Spring boot application, it loads the spring boot first before running the tests.**

I have tried changing the versions of maven-cucumber-reporting, adding the tags of json files & testFailureIgnore etc but nothing helped

**My Runner Class:**

```
package BDD;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features",
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports","json:target/cucumber.json","junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml"},
        monochrome = true,
        strict=true        )


public class CucumberTest {
}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sagar.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-springboot-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.6</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for CUCUMBER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>





    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>firstspringbootproject</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                            <!--<cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>-->
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <param>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!--<checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>-->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I get the below error, when i run my tests from command prompt (mvn verify) -

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  38.981 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-13T17:54:55+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:4.2.3:generate (execution) on project first-springboot-project: Error Found:: BUILD FAILED - Check Report For Details -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When i open the report(overview-features.html) -

```
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:58)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.execute(CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

There is one more point, my cucumber tests ran before it starts generating the report, but it shows below like this:

Below is my Scenario:

```
Now User validates the Slot dates with the Exception Dates

  Scenario: Test GetDates Scenario End to End test    # features/Demo.feature:4
    Given User hits the  getDates API Service Request # StepDefs.user_hits_the_getDates_API_Service_Request(DataTable)
    When User gets the getDates API Service Response  # StepDefs.user_gets_the_getDates_API_Service_Response()
    Then User validates Response from Database        # StepDefs.user_validates_Response_from_Database()
```

then get below messages on CMD:

```
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
0m5.222s

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 25.99 sec - in BDD.CucumberTest
2019-08-13 17:54:51.021  INFO 30012 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@385ef531: startup date [Tue Aug 13 17:54:39 BST 2019]; root of context hierarchy

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ first-springboot-project ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\sagar.wadhwa\SCDT\BLOOM\PREBLOOM\adrs3\firstspringbootproject\target\first-springboot-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ first-springboot-project ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:4.2.3:generate (execution) @ first-springboot-project ---
[INFO] About to generate Cucumber report.
Aug 13, 2019 5:54:54 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage
INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No report file was added!
        at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:58)
        at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
        at net.masterthought.cucumber.CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.execute(CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

CAN ANYONE HELP WITH THIS PLEASE?

Comment: The error is due to cucumber.json file missing on the target folder. Did your cucumber tests run before this report generation kicks in?

Comment: Hi Sureshmani - Yes, my cucumber tests ran before this report generation started! :)
But it shows like this below:

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED MY QUESTION ABOVE! Apologies for less details.

Comment: Also, my target folder has got the cucumber.json file under target./Cucumber-reports/cucumber.json as mentioned in my runner class above.

Comment: I have removed the testng dependencies but still got the same build error

Comment: Try changing the scope of the dependency to compile for cucumber-reporting and run it.  <scope>compile</scope>

Comment: Hi Sureshmani - Tried after changing the scope of cucumber-reporting, but didnt work still!
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Seems like - Issue is that its not able to pick or read the .json file which gets generated after the cucumber tests run! not sure why? I have tried many things now, but still no luck! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the version to 3.15.0 of maven-cucumber-reporting, resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this from the log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:4.2.3:generate (execution) on project first-springboot-project: Error Found:: BUILD FAILED - Check Report For Details -> [Help 1]
```

Had the same output. I knew the tests are fine and that the problem is not there. But something lets the report not be generated. Could only be the feature and Scenario tag from the feature file. After a couple of trys, and after changing (shortening) the filenames, it ran again. So, giving a shorter file name to the feature file, it worked again.